# updating packages in older R version with new R version

Tags: r

I have updated my R version from 3.6 to 4.0.3. Is there a way I can keep all the old packages under 3.6 in 4.0.3 version? I copied all the packages from 3.6 to 4.0.3 and ran

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

I am still getting errors and R studio once closed does not open up. What is the best way to get all my old packages to work with R new version.

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend against copying files directly over into the new directory. You could run `dput(rownames(installed.packages()))` in your old version of R to get a character vector of all installed packages. and then run `install.packages(...)` with that character vector in your new R (assuming all packages came from CRAN). For more specific help, you should include specific errors that you are getting.

Comment: I have already installed R version 4 now. And when I launch R studio, it shows the latest version(4.0.3). so how can I now use old R version so that I can use `dput(rownames(installed.packages()))`

Comment: Just don't use RStudio. The R GUI for your old version will be on your computer somewhere (it doesn't get removed by default). I'm not sure what OS you are using, but just open the correct R application however you normally would.

Comment: I am using Mac OS and yes the previous version is present here `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library`. I am reading about rswitch which switch between versions